Can't generate a private new key on a brand new project and new organization

I've created a brand new account using a purchased domain.
I've set up a new Firebase project.
Enabled billing, upgraded to Blaze plan.
When trying to generate a new private key so I can use the Python Admin SDK, I am denied, receiving the statement: "You've reached the maximum limit on the number of keys for this service account. Delete an existing key from the Google API Console and try again."

When I created an account for personal use few weeks ago (wherein I finished building the MVP for our startup), I had no issues generating the private key.
Where do I start debugging this?

Searching through Stack Overflow. Closest solution I could find was this, but it didn't resolve the issue for me: How can I get the file "service_account.json" for Google Translate API?
Tried creating new projects, but I am denied the ability to generate new private keys regardless of project.

UPDATE #1:

I've tried going to 'Service Accounts' under 'IAM & Admin' on Google Cloud Console, selected 'firebase-adminsdk', pressed 'Keys' tab, and pressed 'Add Key', then 'JSON'. It denied me stating: "The organization policy constraint 'iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation' is enforced on your organization."

Why am I having this issue on this new account, but I didn't have this issue on my personal account?
UPDATE #2:

Tried to remove the policy constraint 'iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation' but got denied, with the following statement: "Required permissions:
All of orgpolicy.policy.get, orgpolicy.policies.create, orgpolicy.policies.delete, orgpolicy.policies.update, orgpolicy.constraints.list, and orgpolicy.policies.list
OR
All of policysimulator.orgPolicyViolationsPreviews.create, orgpolicy.customConstraints.get, orgpolicy.constraints.list, orgpolicy.policies.list, cloudasset.assets.searchAllResources, cloudasset.assets.listResource, and cloudasset.assets.exportResource"

At this point I'm concerned about removing all of these constraints because I do not want to expose myself for any security risks.

did this solves? please see.
